# write content of nshomedirectory in array

Tags: uitableview, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am new in iPhone programming.

I would like to get the content of the NSHomeDirectory to an array.

I have found this code

```
NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Point to Document directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]];
```

Could someone give me a way to put the files in an nsmutablearray?!?

please help me

Comment: Please use comments to request clarification under individual answers. Answers themselves should be just that, solutions that solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just constructing an NSMutableArray with the returned array?

```
NSMutableArray *files = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]];
```

Or use `mutableCopy` on the returned array?

```
NSMutableArray *files = [[fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your information and the sample code. Isnt the home directory the directory of my app?!? In which directory are I supposed to download files?!?

Comment: @DennisW83: It isn't mentioned in [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSHomeDirectory), but it seems you're right. I'd download files to `NSTemporaryDirectory()`, or a directory returned by `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` (with `NSDocumentDirectory`, `NSCachesDirectory`, or `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` as the directory and `NSUserDomainMask` as the domainMask), depending on what I was going to do with it.